# Collision Detection with MANY objects

Tags: java, collision-detection

I mainly focused on the Graphics aspects to create a little 2DGame. I've watched/looked at several tutorials but none of them were that pleasing. I already have a player(a square) moving and colliding with other squares on the screen. Gravity etc. Are also done.

If there are only that much objects as seen on the screen (30*20), everything works perfectly fine. But if I increase it to let's say 300*300 the program starts to run very slow since it has to check for so many objects.

I really don't get how games like Minecraft can work with ALL THOSE blocks and my program already gives up on 300*300 blocks.

I already tried to ONLY check for collisions when the objects are visible, but that leads to the program checking every single object for it's visibility leading to the same problem.
What am I doing wrong? Help appreciated.

I'll post some code on how I handle the collisions.

```
player.collision(player, wall);

public void collision(Tile object1, Tile[] object2){
    collisionCheckUp(object1, object2);
    collisionCheckDown(object1, object2);
    collisionCheckLeft(object1, object2);
    collisionCheckRight(object1, object2);  
}

public void collisionCheckDown(Tile object1, Tile[] object2){

    for (int i = 0; i < Map.tileAmount; i++){
        if(object2[i] != null && object2[i].visible)
        {
            if(object1.isCollidingDown(object2[i])){
                object1.collisionDown = true;
                return;
            }

        }
    }       
    object1.collisionDown = false;
}

public void compileHullDown(){

     collisionHull = new Rectangle((int)x+3, (int)y+3, width-6, height);
}

int wallCount = 0;
    for (int x=0;x<Map.WIDTH;x++) {
        for (int y=0;y<Map.HEIGHT;y++) {

            if (Map.data[x][y] == Map.BLOCKED) {
                wall[wallCount] = new Tile(x * Map.TILE_SIZE, y *  Map.TILE_SIZE);
                wallCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's some missing code here. What's `Map.tileAmount`? Are you checking to far away from the object in question? How does the collision detection actually work? Are you skipping as much space as possible between grid locations?

Comment: Map.tileAmount is just WIDTH(30)*HEIGHT(20) of the map, hence the amount of objetcs(squares) on the map. The Collision Detections works via .intersectes between the rectangles. I have four of those above,below,left and right of the player to check where the collision with a wall occurs. (if the for example the above one collides with a wall gravity is set to 0). added the Object Creation Code to the question.

Comment: I'm not clear on your strategy: you should have a collection of objects; you don't need to go through the entire map. For the list of currently-valid objects, you'll have their location. From their location you can check the surrounding grid locations on the map to see if they're occupied. In any case, there are a ton of collision detection algorithms on the web--which one is most appropriate may depend on your game world implementation.

Comment: relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eED4bSkYCB8

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The usual approach to optimize collision detection is to use a [space partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) to classify/manage your objects.

The general idea of the approach is that you build a tree representing the space and put your objects into that tree, according to their positions. When you calculate the collisions, you traverse the tree. This way, you will have to perform significantly less calculations than using the brute force approach, because you will be ignoring all objects in  branches other than the one you're traversing. Minecraft and similar probably use [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for collision (and maybe for rendering too).

The most common space partition structures are [BSP-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), [kd-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) (a special type of BSP-trees). The simpler approach would be to use a uniform space partition for the start - split your space in axis-aligned halves.

The best resource on collision that I have discovered is [this book](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/1558607323?tag=realtimecolli-20). It should clarify all your questions on the topic.

That's if you wanted to do it right. If you want to do it quick, you could just sample the color buffer around your character, or only in the movement direction to determine if an obstacle is close.

Answer (score 5):

As Kostja mentioned, it will be useful for you to partition your space. However, you will need to use [QuadTrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) instead of Octrees as you are only in 2D not 3D.
Here are is a nice [article](http://www.kyleschouviller.com/wsuxna/quadtree-source-included/) to get you started on QuadTrees.

Comment: I'd gladly do that, but I need 15 reputation to be able to do so :/

Answer (score 0):

You can cut your overhead by a factor of 4 by, instead of calculating collisions for up/down/left/right, calculating collisions once and using the relative positions of the two objects to find out if you hit a floor, wall, or ceiling. Another good idea is to only pay attention to the objects that are nearby - maybe once every 0.25 seconds make a list of all objects that are probably close enough to collide with in the next 0.25 seconds?